# How to make chat message bubble with emotion icon and text windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, chat, datatemplate

I'm developing a chat application and of course when we message to each other, everyone may love to use emotion icon to express their feeling.

But I'm stuck with emotion in text message. How can I insert multi emotion icon images inside a text line of textblock in message listbox data template ? Could anyone give me a solution for this problem ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `textblock` use a `RichTextBox` in data template. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28VS.95%29.aspx#inline_images_or_other_elements).
I developed a chat app and this is what I've done:
Say I've a sticker pack **CoolStickers**. Every sticker pack is associated with an unique id (`Guid` may be). Whenever I install a Sticker I put all the images of the sticker pack in `/stickers/{uniueIdOfStickerPack}`. When I send message with sticker I insert something like `[[[{uniueIdOfStickerPack}/{stickerId}]]]`. When reciever recieves the message the app first check if `/stickers/{uniueIdOfStickerPack}` path is available or not. If available it inserts the particular sticker otherwise it prompts the user to install the pack.

Comment: Tks for ur answer but does this work on richtextbox of windows phone :)

Comment: Yes! rtf would work on any silverlight supported platform but the procedure may be a bit different from the current link. I'm updating the link with relevant context.